# How to read HDF5 attributes (metadata) with Python and h5py

Tags: python, python-3.x, metadata, hdf5, h5py

I have a HDF5 file with multiple folders inside. Each folder has attributes added (some call attributes "metadata"). I know how to access the keys inside a folder, but I don't know how to pull the attributes with Python's `h5py` package.
Here are attributes from HDFView:

```
Folder1(800,4)
    Group size = 9
    Number of attributes = 1
        measRelTime_seconds = 201.73
```

I need to pull this `measRelTime_seconds` value. I already have a loop to read files:

```py
f = h5py.File(file, 'r')
for k, key in enumerate(f.keys()): #loop over folders
    #need to obtain measRelTime_seconds here, I guess
```

Comment: What do  you mean by `metadata`?  `h5py` can read the `.attr` that's may be attached to the file, a group or dataset.

Comment: There are two tabs when I open the file on viewer: Log Info and Metadata. I can't use .attrs either. I tried `f.attrs` but it only returns `<Attributes of HDF5 object at 140490175897088>`. Can you tell me how to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I find my answer. To read it You can simply check the name of the attribute as

```
f['Folder'].attrs.keys()
```

and the value can be returned with

```
f['Folder'].attrs['<name of the attribute>']
```

Answer (score 15):

Attributes work  just like groups and datasets. Use `object.attrs.keys()` to iterate over the attribute names. The object could be a file, group or dataset.

Here is a simple example that creates 2 attributes on 3 different objects, then reads and prints them.

```
arr = np.random.randn(1000)

with h5py.File('groups.hdf5', 'w') as f:
    g = f.create_group('Base_Group')
    d = g.create_dataset('default', data=arr)

    f.attrs['User'] = 'Me'
    f.attrs['OS'] = 'Windows'

    g.attrs['Date'] = 'today'
    g.attrs['Time'] = 'now'

    d.attrs['attr1'] = 1.0
    d.attrs['attr2'] = 22.2
    
    for k in f.attrs.keys():
        print(f"{k} => {f.attrs[k]}")
    for k in g.attrs.keys():
        print(f"{k} => {g.attrs[k]}")
    for k in d.attrs.keys():
        print(f"{k} => {d.attrs[k]}")

    print('*****')
    
    for k in f.attrs.keys():
        print(f"{k} => {f.attrs[k]}")
    for k in f['Base_Group'].attrs.keys():
        print(f"{k} => {f['Base_Group'].attrs[k]}")
    for k in f['Base_Group']['default'].attrs.keys():
        print(f"{k} => {f['Base_Group']['default'].attrs[k]}")
```