# 'ValuesViewHDF5' object has no attribute 'attrs'

Tags: python-3.x, h5py

```
f = h5py.File(data_dir+rec_filename+'.hdf5', 'r')
trial = f.values() #_._next_() #.next()
equilibrate = trial.attrs['equilibrate']
```

this synatax gives me error: 'ValuesViewHDF5' object has no attribute 'attrs'. Does anyone know why I get this error?

I tried to search if the syntax for the new h5py has changed but couldn't find anything relevant.
Maybe it is a problem related to incpomatibilities between python2.x and python3.x

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: my question is: why do I get the error: 'ValuesViewHDF5' object has no attribute 'attrs'

Comment: I don't see in the docs anything about a fileobject having either `values` or `attrs`.  Groups and datasets can have `attrs`.  And `attrs` can have `values`.  If you think otherwise, could you point us to the relevant documentation section(s)?

Comment: I also see in the docs https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/attr.html that groups have attributes. In that case what would be an alternative syntax for my posted code? I am trying altrenatives. It could be that 'equilibrate' is a group attribute of the file, unsure how to access it.

Comment: Since you are reading the file, you are constrained by what was written to the file.  Typically a file has one more groups, each of which may have more groups or datasets.  `h5py` uses a dict like interface to the file and groups.  They may also have `attr`.  Best bet is to read the docs.  We can't   lead you to discovering the structure of a file we can't access.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `equilibrate` attribute on the file object, you need to use this line:
`equilibrate = f.attrs['equilibrate']`

However as @hpaulj mentioned, you need to confirm the `equilibrate` attribute exists. You can access and print all attributes at the file level with this code:

```
with h5py.File(data_dir+rec_filename+'.hdf5', 'r') as f:   
    for k in f.attrs.keys():
        print(f"{k} => {f.attrs[k]}")
```

Complete details about creating and reading attributes with h5py are available in this answer to a similar question:
[How to read HDF5 attributes (metadata) with Python and h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66147416/10462884)

BTW, why are you using `f.values()`? It does NOT return the file object. If you inspect the returned object, you will find it has the objects from the referenced group (e.g., Group and Dataset objects for `f`, the file object). Repeating what @hpaulj said, `h5py` uses dictionary syntax to access group and dataset names and/or objects (but they are not dictionaries!). The keys are the object names and the values are the objects. Here is a simple example showing how the dictionary syntax behaves:

```
with h5py.File(data_dir+rec_filename+'.hdf5', 'r') as f:   
    for k in f:  # get the keys, eg the object names
        print(f"Object name: {k}")
    for k in f.keys():  # same as example above
        print(f"Object name: {k}")
    for v in f.values(): # get the values, eg the objects
        print(f"Object: {v}; name: {v.name}")
    for k,v in f.items():  # get the keys and values
        print(f"Object name: {k}; Object: {v}")
```